# Octave C++ API: How to execute ocaml string ond output results?

Tags: c++, string, api, octave

I want having some string with octave expressions execute it from C++ API and print results onto consol. How to do such thing? In what header what function can do that for me?

For example giving `exp(i*pi)` I want to get `-1` into some variable (stringbuf for example) and be capable to do with it anething - from casting to int to using it as string=)

Comment: See my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246444/how-to-embed-the-gnu-octave-in-c-c-program/)