# How to embed the GNU Octave in C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, controls, package, octave

I want to calculate some matrix algorithms using the GNU Octave library. I know I can use C/C++ API of Octave for basic use. However the method I want to use is not in the default packages of Octave. So how to use Octave's [control package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/control/) in the C/C++ program?

Comment: I am new to use Octave in C++. Can you please show me how to use C/C++ API of Octave to realize it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 22):

Something like this

**embed.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/octave.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv)
{
  int embedded;
  octave_main(argc,argv,embedded=0);  
  return embedded;
}
```

Then

`mkoctfile embed.cpp --link-stand-alone -o embed` in order to make a standalone executable.

To call octave functions whether they are provided by scripts or octaveforge modules you can then use feval which takes the octave function name as string, an octave_value_list of the input variables to that function, and the number of variables to that function as integer.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs) for further information.

Comment: Food for thought for anyone who lands here: using embed octave means you must release your code under a GPL like license http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#If_I_write_code_using_Octave_do_I_have_to_release_it_under_the_GPL.3F