# Nonlinear optimization C

Tags: c, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to perform a non-linear optimization algorithm using C.

The problem is:
[image: optimization problem]
over the five points that are in vector X.

X, Y(X), lower and upper bounds are known.

I have found the **nlopt** library on C but I do not know if It is possible to perform the optimization over the five discrete points.

Anything to suggest, even another library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).  For nonlinear programming on Octave, refer to 
[Octave Optimization](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Optimization.html#Optimization).
You could implement using matlab-like language.

It also has C/C++ api.
See this post: [How to embed the GNU Octave in C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246444/how-to-embed-the-gnu-octave-in-c-c-program).

And also, [this pdf](https://f88618e8-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/recheliunew/researchblog/misccintegrationofoctave/howto-octave-c%2B%2B.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crhaeCH5ofRzAeib8BzaQyJeWjPoFmuGddibAH_7cGt2Fuk2DnluV6iDNBKgDXi7l-qu1sYvzoDAjGOIgLCM15i9EevYwGIhvSNNQ-UF3a-uEWVyw3BSCAELsDP2OdJ0DZ9tXmclzQQ2vChvVb-zKCRW6ykSdLqZfpeGUj2SE-n6qv9ym0CXJVzF4H-ZuwFPqLUG8n_5_M46XrecitpiXpCRivZgecT5zMCOlbuGr_udWm2TEqh6zp29LI4TCODN47yD0Muml2QvhhniTQa6HBYhBDpQw%3D%3D&attredirects=0)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

I have already implement the optimization in Matlab but the algorithm is quite slow, that's why I want to switch in C.

Do you think in Octave it will be sufficient fast?
Thanks!

Comment: @user2010599 octave is implemented in C++, but has C/C++ api. It might be easier if you already know matlab.  As to the efficiency, I'm not quite sure, you might have to try.

Comment: @koel, Matlab is generally faster than Octave.

Answer (score 0):

Consider optimizing matlab code instead of reimplementing algorithm in another language - matlab can be pretty fast if optimized properly (avoid using for loop, use vectorized computations, pre-allocate memory).

Take a look at  http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/june07/patterns.html

Comment: I am solving the optimization problem using the matlab function **lsqnonlin**, so there is not a lot of code to change. (it takes time to finish because I run the optimization for every voxel of a 3D image). 
Maybe I can resolve the problem using my own method (like Langrange multipliers) but I do not know if it worths to do this compared with the execution time I will save.

Comment: Does running optimization for each voxel if 3D image means that isqnonlin is executed separately for each voxel? So, you have N X arrays, each containing 5 points, and optimization is performed independently for all of them?

Comment: Yes, the image is 512*256 and I have 5 of these arrays. The optimmization is performed for each voxel of the image.

Comment: *for each slice. But don't be confused. The opimizations are uncorellated. I want to solve the problem efficiently for a single voxel.