# c++/objective-c use octave withouth installed

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, octave

I'm currently working on a project for my university, where I have to develop an iOS app. For this I would like to work with octave. My question is, if it's possible to use my octave code as a c++ library without having octave installed, which I just can include to my Objective-C project and give the input to the library, which computes the result and return the output to my project.

I already searched the web, but I couldn't find anything :/

Best regards,
Carsten

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246444/how-to-embed-the-gnu-octave-in-c-c-program  check this question.

Comment: i checked it, but the standalone executable needs to have octave installed on the system or am I wrong?