# Embedding Octave in Visual C++ 2017 program

Tags: visual-c++, octave

Is it possible to embed Octave in a C++ program compiled with Visual Studio 2017?

(Something like [How to embed the GNU Octave in C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246444/how-to-embed-the-gnu-octave-in-c-c-program))

Octave Windows binaries are compiled with MinGW, so its libraries can't be linked with Visual Studio linker.

Comment: The simple solution is that you can create an octave process so it can evaluate a string or run a file. However if you need to call its internal API you can use its  C [mex interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176203/call-gnu-octave-functions-in-c). Nearly all the functions that begins with mx or mex that are included in liboctinterp-X.dll can be used. But you need to create a def file and make an [import library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529770/how-to-use-libraries-compiled-with-mingw-in-msvc) for the needed functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about the mex interface. You could make an answer instead of a comment, so I can flag it as the corrent answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I currently don't have an access to msvc to provide a full answer. Regarding the informations if you could provide a more complete answer I will upvote!

Comment: and always keep in mind that you have to release your code also under GPLv2 if you link against GNU Octave